# How to access Html Links which are in Master Page in View in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, master-pages

I have three links inside master page up on clicking those three links user will be navigated to respective views.

The point is I need to high light the link from which he came to the view.

```
<ul class="yearPicker" style="list-style: none;">
        <li class="first">
          <%=
    this.Html.ActionLink("Day Planner", "Index", "Travel", null, new { style = "text-decoration:none;" })%></li>
        <li>
          <%=
    this.Html.ActionLink(
      "Executive Briefing", "Index", "ExecutiveBriefing", new { Id = 0 }, new { style = "text-decoration:none;" })%></li>
        <li class="last">
          <%=this.Html.ActionLink("News", "Index", "LFF", null, new { style = "text-decoration:none;" })%></li>
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom helper to generate those links as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7066862/29407). The helper will check the current controller and action and apply a CSS style to the link if they match.